# White lines during boot before Windows boot manager

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, vga, visual-artifacts

Sometimes, when I turn on my laptop, it shows some white lines that disappear inmediatly

[Video](https://youtu.be/3iVq6Q55u3I)

Lines are practically inappreciable

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pCqB.jpg)

It happens randomly and white lines are showed the instant the screen lights up. Furthermore, if I access BIOS settings from Windows (restore this PC -> advanced restart -> UEFI settings) it will randomly show those white lines on screen.

I have run every single test in UEFI diagnostics and updated BIOS and SSD firmware. How can I solve it?

Comment: It's probably a defective panel. Send it to repair.

Comment: Do they always disappear once the system begins to boot? I have a machine [2 in fact, almost identical]  that does similar all the way until the custom GPU drivers & profile load about halfway through the boot process.

Comment: If lines appear, they are shown in that screen and once that drivers get loaded and windows is running, they don't return.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't worry about it then, unless it gets worse.

Comment: Perhaps the boot screen is at a different resolution or refresh rate from when running, and the monitor takes a second to sync properly between resolutions.